# Is $\int \frac{\ln(1+\exp(a_1x-a_2))}{1+\exp(a_3x^2+a_4x+a_5)} dx$ analytically integrable?

Tags: integration

The integral

$\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{\ln(1+\exp(a_1x-a_2))}{1+\exp(a_3x^2+a_4x+a_5)} dx$

seems like it is not analytically integrable. Nevertheless, how could I construct an analytical approximation to this integral?

$a_1 > 0$ and $a_2 > 0$, no constraints for $a_3$ to $a_5$.

Comment: Do you have any knowledge about the constants (e.g., positive)?

Comment: Added some info about the constants.